# Что такое маршалинг?

Tags: c#, .net

Как бы вы объяснили "на пальцах", или с примером кода что это такое?
Вот сериализация - это ясно, это копирование структур из-в в простой форме, например в форме байтового потока. И вот утверждается, что в этом случае сериализация по своей сути является маршалингом так как реализует "pass-by-value semantics". Что думаете?

Comment: [Аналогичный вопрос на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/770474/2076787). Можно перевести ответ.

Comment: Думаю,  статья об этом https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @D-side я в принципе оттуда и брал для своего вопроса информацию... Но мне хотелось услышать на родном, могучем и великом.

Comment: @YuryBakharev это ссылка на документацию мало что помогает понять. Сериализация в json - это есть маршалинг или нет?

Comment: @ Bulson Эта документация на примере .net объекта, по мне так в комментариях с трудностями перевод но все же описывается основной смысл, ЧТО ЭТО ПРИВЕДЕНИЕ ОБЪЕКТОВ К ТАКОМУ АБСТРАКТНОМУ ТИПУ  КОТОРЫЕ БУДУТ ВЫЗЫВАТЬСЯ РАЗНЫМИ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯМИ  И МОГУТ БЫТЬ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНЫ В РАЗНЫХ ЯЗЫКАХ как пример. Сериализация в json чего? Строки? XML? - нет это не маршалинг имхо.

Comment: @Bulson, Сериализация в json - это, как вы сами написали, сериализация, а не маршалинг.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Маршаллинг - это передача сущности из одного контекста в другой. Сериализация - это запись в виде последовательности элементов.

Маршаллинг - это процесс более высокого уровня, чем сериализация. Обычно, если надо передать структуру данных из одного процесса в другой - ее сериализуют, передают и десериализуют. Если параметр двусторонний - то и передавать его надо будет два раза, при этом это будет *одна* операция маршаллинга.

Или возможна передача по ссылке, когда на другой стороне канала создается прокси-объект, а через канал передается не внутреннее состояние объекта, а вызовы его методов.

Если речь идет о взаимодействии между управляемым и неуправляемым кодом - то маршаллинг заключается в фиксировании адресов объектов или в копировании структур между управляемой и неуправляемой памятью, сериализация тут вовсе не используется.

Comment: Я принимаю ваш ответ, но с оговоркой, точнее дополнением:
 "So Serialization is part of Marshalling." "In Marshalling Object is serialized(member data is serialzied) + Codebase is attached."

Comment: @Bulson при маршаллинге структур между управляемым и неуправляемым кодом сериализации не происходит.

Comment: ОК, понял. Я эти цитаты взял с англ.версии SO

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, маршалинг и сериализация это почти синонимы, за исключением того, что при маршалинге записываются различные допольнительные данные которые говорят получателю объекта что сним делать и как - тоесть кодовая база. Можно сказать что Маршалинг это сериализация данных плюс кодовой базы объекта.